# is there any benchmarks for comparing the methods of visual slam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have studied the matlab code of Javier Civera's 1-point RANSAC for EKF MonoSLAM, but I find I am lack of some datasets to evaluate the visual slam system, because I don't have the powerful robot to collect good data sets.
does any one know some image dataset to test the visual SLAM methods ? or else, tell me some good simulator  to implement the visual SLAM methods and finally evaluate the methods

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52861/is-there-any-benchmarks-for-comparing-the-methods--of-visual-slam/) by [peterli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4011/peterli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a dataset designed to "establish a novel benchmark for the evaluation of visual odometry and visual SLAM systems" by Jürgen Sturm at TUM:

http://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset

Hope that helps...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2013-01-20**:
Here's also the paper about that dataset: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvision.in.tum.de%2F_media%2Fspezial%2Fbib%2Fendres12icra.pdf&ei=VAf9UK6QIcSAtAaS_4G4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEJgauHEKqNQbiPCgkcVbNY3TisjQ&sig2=iamLPUhgTUA8yloNx8Oeag&bv